# addition of numbers in existing div box

Tags: jquery, math, addition

How would I go about adding a sum to an existing number on a page?

Would it be better to just use a `.empty()` and then doing the sum via jQuery and setting it again in `.html()`?

Example

```
<div class="price">$200</div>
```

Then jQuery would add `$50` to that existing price and the new price would be `$250`.

Depending on radio selection `Yes` adds `$50` while `No` just leaves it the way it is.

What happens if they select back and fourth, any way of undoing that last addition?

Comment: `$(.price).text( '$' + (parseInt($(.price).text(),10) + 50)  );`

Comment: That solution is completely unnecessary. You would keep track of the value as a local variable, then update the text of the div whenever an event (ie click) happens.

Answer (score 3):

Store the price in the element:

```
<div class="product" data-price="50.0">I'm a product</div>
```

And just add them up whenever something changes:

```
var total = 0;

$('.product').filter(function() {
    // Remove the ones that aren't checked or something
    return true;
}).each(function() {
    total += $(this).data('price');
});

$('.price').text('$' + total);
```